# How to prevent overflow hide for video item in IE 11 when slider move next & previous?

Tags: html, html5-video, internet-explorer-11, owl-carousel

I have used Owl Carousel which have 3 HTML-5 Video & auto-play mode.
First Item is Video and 4th and 7th are videos.
When i run in IE-11 every third image item comes video which not hide.

Basically, my requirements is when video item comes video should autoplay and not run any next item until video end. if video end then next slide come.
this all working good chrome & Mozilla but IE-11 have video item not proper hide.

```
var owl = window.jQuery('.slider_owl');
        window.jQuery('.slider_owl').owlCarousel({
            items: 1,
            loop: true,
            dots: false,
            video: true,
            autoplay:true,
            autoplayHoverPause:false,
            autoplayTimeout:5000, 
            responsive : {
                768 : {
                    onInitialized: function () {
                        if ($(".owl-item.active video", this.$element).length) {
                            $(".owl-item.active video", this.$element)[0].play();

                            owl.trigger('stop.owl.autoplay');
                            $(".owl-item.active video", this.$element).on('ended', function () {
                                owl.trigger('play.owl.autoplay')
                            });
                        }
                    },
                    onTranslated: function () {
                        if ($(".owl-item.active video", this.$element).length) {
                            $(".owl-item.active video", this.$element)[0].play();
                            owl.trigger('stop.owl.autoplay');
                            $(".owl-item.active video", this.$element).on('ended', function () {
                                owl.trigger('play.owl.autoplay')
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }
            }           
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

From your description, since you are using HTML 5 video element, I suggest you could try to add an event listener to detect whether the video is displaying or ended, then stop/start the owlCarousel.

Please refer to this sample to add an event listener to the video element.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="output"></div>
<video id="myVideo" width="320" height="176" controls autoplay>
    <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/tags/mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
</video>
<script>
    var media = document.getElementById('myVideo');

    // Playing event
    media.addEventListener("playing", function() {
        $("#output").html("Playing event triggered");
    });

    // Pause event
    media.addEventListener("pause", function() {
        $("#output").html("Pause event triggered");
    });

    //End event
    media.addEventListener("ended", function () {
        $("#output").html("Ended event triggered");
    });
</script>
```

Then, in the playing and ended function, you could start/stop the owlCarousel using the following command:

```
owl.trigger('play.owl.autoplay')
```

or

```
 owl.trigger('stop.owl.autoplay')
```

More detail information about OwlCarousel Autoplay, you could check [this article](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/autoplay.html).

Comment: Thank you for reply.
Yes i am will check & give review.